# Java LinkedHashMap get first or last entry

Tags: java, dictionary, linkedhashmap

I have used [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) because it is important the order in which keys entered in the map.

But now I want to get the value of key in the first place (the first entered entry) or the last.

Should there be a method like `first()` and `last()` or something like that?

Do I need to have an iterator to just get the first key entry? That is why I used [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)!

Thanks!

Comment: The situation is indeed unfortunate. Here is the (low-priority) feature request that would provide what you need: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6266354

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30984049/1808829 could help you

Comment: I don't understand why `LinkedHashMap` doesn't implement `Deque`. It might as well.

Comment: To follow up on @KevinBourrillion's comment from 13 years ago, this is finally being added in Java 21 by the [sequenced collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) feature ([JDK-8280836](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8280836)).  I've added this as an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76461679/1108305).

Answer (score 196, accepted):

The semantics of `LinkedHashMap` are still those of a Map, rather than that of a `LinkedList`. It retains insertion order, yes, but that's an implementation detail, rather than an aspect of its interface.

The quickest way to get the "first" entry is still `entrySet().iterator().next()`. Getting the "last" entry is possible, but will entail iterating over the whole entry set by calling `.next()` until you reach the last.  `while (iterator.hasNext()) { lastElement = iterator.next() }`

**edit**: However, if you're willing to go beyond the JavaSE API, [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/) has its own [`LinkedMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LinkedMap.html) implementation, which has methods like [`firstKey`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/AbstractLinkedMap.html#firstKey--) and [`lastKey`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/AbstractLinkedMap.html#lastKey--), which do what you're looking for. The interface is considerably richer.

Comment: I have to insert entry(key, value) as a first entry in my linked map; OR something like index based insertion. is that possible with Apache collections?

Comment: The "LinkedMap," "firstKey," and "lastKey" links are stale, fyi.

Comment: Appears you actually maybe can even use the Commons LinkedMap to traverse it in reverse order, by getting lastKey then using previousKey after that to step backward...nice.

Comment: Appears you actually maybe can even use the Commons LinkedMap to traverse it in reverse order, by getting lastKey then using previousKey after that to step backward...nice. You could then even write your own Iterable if you wanted to use it in foreach loops ex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1098153/32453

Comment: results in infinite loop, because lastentry .next returns the first entry

Comment: how can i convert from LinkedHashMap to apache LinkedMap?

Comment: @skaffman , could you please help : what is `mylinkedmap.entrySet().iterator().next()` time complexity? Is it O(1) ?

Comment: @tkrishtop late answer but I believe it should be O(1) as the LinkedHashMap has a pointer to the head of the queue.

Answer (score 30):

Can you try doing something like (to get the last entry):

```
linkedHashMap.entrySet().toArray()[linkedHashMap.size() -1];
```

Comment: It is still faster to iterate and keep the last item.  `T last = null ; for( T item : linkedHashMap.values() ) last = item;`  Or something like that.  It is O(N) in time but O(1) in memory.

Comment: @FlorianF So it depends how big is your list. The array solution would be faster and wouldn't compromise memory if the collection is not that big, otherwise it's better taking longer to iterate thru it... I wonder if there's a bit of both as a solution, especially since Java 8.

Comment: @skinny_jones: Why would the array solution be faster? It still involves iterating over the whole map, it's just that now the iteration is inside a JDK method instead of explicit.

Answer (score 28):

I know that I came too late but I would like to offer some alternatives, not something extraordinary but some cases that none mentioned here. In case that someone doesn't care so much for efficiency but he wants something with more simplicity(perhaps find the last entry value with one line of code), all this will get quite simplified with the arrival of
  [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) . I provide some useful scenarios.

For the sake of the completeness, I compare these alternatives with the solution of arrays that already mentioned in this post by others users. I sum up all the cases and i think they would be useful(when performance does matter or no) especially for new developers, always depends on the matter of each problem

### Possible Alternatives

#### Usage of Array Method

I took it from the previous answer to to make the follow comparisons. This solution belongs @feresr.

```
  public static String FindLasstEntryWithArrayMethod() {
        return String.valueOf(linkedmap.entrySet().toArray()[linkedmap.size() - 1]);
    }
```

#### Usage of ArrayList Method

Similar to the first solution with a little bit different performance

```
public static String FindLasstEntryWithArrayListMethod() {
        List<Entry<Integer, String>> entryList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>(linkedmap.entrySet());
        return entryList.get(entryList.size() - 1).getValue();
    }
```

#### Reduce Method

This method will reduce the set of elements until getting the last element of stream. In addition, it will  return only deterministic results

```
public static String FindLasstEntryWithReduceMethod() {
        return linkedmap.entrySet().stream().reduce((first, second) -> second).orElse(null).getValue();
    }
```

#### SkipFunction Method

This method will get the last element of the stream  by simply skipping all the elements before it

```
public static String FindLasstEntryWithSkipFunctionMethod() {
        final long count = linkedmap.entrySet().stream().count();
        return linkedmap.entrySet().stream().skip(count - 1).findFirst().get().getValue();
    }
```

#### Iterable Alternative

> Iterables.getLast from Google Guava. It has some optimization for
>   Lists and SortedSets too

```
public static String FindLasstEntryWithGuavaIterable() {
        return Iterables.getLast(linkedmap.entrySet()).getValue();
    }
```

Here is the full source code

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class PerformanceTest {

    private static long startTime;
    private static long endTime;
    private static LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> linkedmap;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        linkedmap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

        linkedmap.put(12, "Chaitanya");
        linkedmap.put(2, "Rahul");
        linkedmap.put(7, "Singh");
        linkedmap.put(49, "Ajeet");
        linkedmap.put(76, "Anuj");

        //call a useless action  so that the caching occurs before the jobs starts.
        linkedmap.entrySet().forEach(x -> {});



        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        FindLasstEntryWithArrayListMethod();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("FindLasstEntryWithArrayListMethod : " + "took " + new BigDecimal((endTime - startTime) / 1000000.000).setScale(3, RoundingMode.CEILING) + " milliseconds");


         startTime = System.nanoTime();
        FindLasstEntryWithArrayMethod();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("FindLasstEntryWithArrayMethod : " + "took " + new BigDecimal((endTime - startTime) / 1000000.000).setScale(3, RoundingMode.CEILING) + " milliseconds");

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        FindLasstEntryWithReduceMethod();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("FindLasstEntryWithReduceMethod : " + "took " + new BigDecimal((endTime - startTime) / 1000000.000).setScale(3, RoundingMode.CEILING) + " milliseconds");

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        FindLasstEntryWithSkipFunctionMethod();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("FindLasstEntryWithSkipFunctionMethod : " + "took " + new BigDecimal((endTime - startTime) / 1000000.000).setScale(3, RoundingMode.CEILING) + " milliseconds");

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        FindLasstEntryWithGuavaIterable();
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("FindLasstEntryWithGuavaIterable : " + "took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");


    }

    public static String FindLasstEntryWithReduceMethod() {
        return linkedmap.entrySet().stream().reduce((first, second) -> second).orElse(null).getValue();
    }

    public static String FindLasstEntryWithSkipFunctionMethod() {
        final long count = linkedmap.entrySet().stream().count();
        return linkedmap.entrySet().stream().skip(count - 1).findFirst().get().getValue();
    }

    public static String FindLasstEntryWithGuavaIterable() {
        return Iterables.getLast(linkedmap.entrySet()).getValue();
    }

    public static String FindLasstEntryWithArrayListMethod() {
        List<Entry<Integer, String>> entryList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>(linkedmap.entrySet());
        return entryList.get(entryList.size() - 1).getValue();
    }

    public static String FindLasstEntryWithArrayMethod() {
        return String.valueOf(linkedmap.entrySet().toArray()[linkedmap.size() - 1]);
    }
}
```

Here is the output with performance of each method

```
FindLasstEntryWithArrayListMethod : took 0.162 milliseconds
FindLasstEntryWithArrayMethod : took 0.025 milliseconds
FindLasstEntryWithReduceMethod : took 2.776 milliseconds
FindLasstEntryWithSkipFunctionMethod : took 3.396 milliseconds
FindLasstEntryWithGuavaIterable : took 11 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 13):

`LinkedHashMap` current implementation (Java 8) keeps track of its tail. If performance is a concern and/or the map is large in size, you could access that field via reflection.

Because the implementation may change it is probably a good idea to have a fallback strategy too. You may want to log something if an exception is thrown so you know that the implementation has changed.

It could look like:

```
public static <K, V> Entry<K, V> getFirst(Map<K, V> map) {
  if (map.isEmpty()) return null;
  return map.entrySet().iterator().next();
}

public static <K, V> Entry<K, V> getLast(Map<K, V> map) {
  try {
    if (map instanceof LinkedHashMap) return getLastViaReflection(map);
  } catch (Exception ignore) { }
  return getLastByIterating(map);
}

private static <K, V> Entry<K, V> getLastByIterating(Map<K, V> map) {
  Entry<K, V> last = null;
  for (Entry<K, V> e : map.entrySet()) last = e;
  return last;
}

private static <K, V> Entry<K, V> getLastViaReflection(Map<K, V> map) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
  Field tail = map.getClass().getDeclaredField("tail");
  tail.setAccessible(true);
  return (Entry<K, V>) tail.get(map);
}
```

Comment: I think I'd add `ClassCastException` to the `catch` just in case `tail` is not an `Entry` in a subclass (or a future implementation).

Comment: @PaulBoddington I've replaced it with a catch all - not recommended in general but probably appropriate here.

Comment: ahh the "dirty" answer :)

Answer (score 6):

One more way to get first and last entry of a LinkedHashMap is to use `toArray()` method of Set interface.

But I think iterating over the entries in the entry set and getting the first and last entry is a better approach.

The usage of array methods leads to warning of the form *" ...needs unchecked conversion to conform to ..."*  which cannot be fixed [but can be only be suppressed by using the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`].

Here is a small example to demonstrate the usage of `toArray()` method:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Map<Integer,String> orderMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
        orderMap.put(6, "Six");
        orderMap.put(7, "Seven");
        orderMap.put(3, "Three");
        orderMap.put(100, "Hundered");
        orderMap.put(10, "Ten");

        final Set<Entry<Integer, String>> mapValues = orderMap.entrySet();
        final int maplength = mapValues.size();
        final Entry<Integer,String>[] test = new Entry[maplength];
        mapValues.toArray(test);

        System.out.print("First Key:"+test[0].getKey());
        System.out.println(" First Value:"+test[0].getValue());

        System.out.print("Last Key:"+test[maplength-1].getKey());
        System.out.println(" Last Value:"+test[maplength-1].getValue());
    }

    // the output geneated is :
    First Key:6 First Value:Six
    Last Key:10 Last Value:Ten
```

Comment: the toArray method itself will iterate over the hashmap again :)
So its rather more inefficient because of the few extra cycles wasted in creating array and the space allocated for the array.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit dirty, but you can override the `removeEldestEntry` method of LinkedHashMap, which it might suit you to do as a private anonymous member:

```
private Splat eldest = null;
private LinkedHashMap<Integer, Splat> pastFutures = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Splat>() {

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<Integer, Splat> eldest) {

        eldest = eldest.getValue();
        return false;
    }
};
```

So you will always be able to get the first entry at your `eldest` member. It will be updated every time you perform a `put`.

It should also be easy to override `put` and set `youngest` ...

```
    @Override
    public Splat put(Integer key, Splat value) {

        youngest = value;
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
```

It all breaks down when you start removing entries though; haven't figured out a way to kludge that.

It's very annoying that you can't otherwise get access to head or tail in a sensible way ...

Comment: Good try, but the eldest entry is updated when map.get is invoked. So eldestEntry will not be updated in those cases, unless put is called after that.

Comment: @vishr eldest entry is updated when put is invoked. (get and put for access order LinkedHashMap)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this :

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> myMap;

public String getFirstKey() {
  String out = null;
  for (int key : myMap.keySet()) {
    out = myMap.get(key);
    break;
  }
  return out;
}

public String getLastKey() {
  String out = null;
  for (int key : myMap.keySet()) {
    out = myMap.get(key);
  }
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Java 21, the first and last entry can be easily accessed using the [`firstEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html#firstEntry()) and [`lastEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html#lastEntry()) methods on `LinkedHashMap`:

```java
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> linkedHashMap = // ...

Entry<Integer, String> firstEntry = linkedHashMap.firstEntry();
Entry<Integer, String> lastValue = linkedHashMap.lastEntry();

Integer firstKey = firstEntry.getKey();
Integer lastKey = lastEntry.getKey();
String firstValue = firstEntry.getValue();
String lastValue = lastEntry.getValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Java8 stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) this can be done very easily:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
linkedHashMap.put("A", 1);
linkedHashMap.put("B", 2);
linkedHashMap.put("C", 3);
linkedHashMap.put("D", 4);

//First entry
Map.Entry<String, Integer> firstEntry = linkedHashMap.entrySet().stream().findFirst().get();

//Last entry
Map.Entry<String, Integer> lastEntry = linkedHashMap.entrySet().stream().skip(linkedHashMap.size() - 1).findFirst().get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

```
map.remove(map.keySet().iterator().next());
```

Comment: it gives the first inserted key in the map. Finding the first key will be in O(1). The problem here is finding a way in O(1) for finding the last inserted key.

Answer (score 2):

For first element use `entrySet().iterator().next()` and stop iterating after 1 iteration.
For last one the easiest way is to preserve the key in a variable whenever you do a map.put.

Answer (score 1):

Though linkedHashMap doesn't provide any method to get first, last or any specific object.

But its pretty trivial to get :

```
Map<Integer,String> orderMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();  
Set<Integer> al =   orderMap.keySet();
```

now using iterator on `al` object ; you can get any object.

Answer (score 1):

```
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Map;

        public class Scratch {
           public static void main(String[] args) {

              // Plain java version

              Map<String, List<Integer>> linked = new LinkedHashMap<>();
              linked.put("a", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
              linked.put("aa", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
              linked.put("b", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
              linked.put("bb", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));

              System.out.println("linked = " + linked);

              String firstKey = getFirstKey(linked);
              System.out.println("firstKey = " + firstKey);
              List<Integer> firstEntry = linked.get(firstKey);
              System.out.println("firstEntry = " + firstEntry);

              String lastKey = getLastKey(linked);
              System.out.println("lastKey = " + lastKey);
              List<Integer> lastEntry = linked.get(lastKey);
              System.out.println("lastEntry = " + lastEntry);



           }

           private static String getLastKey(Map<String, List<Integer>> linked) {
              int index = 0;
              for (String key : linked.keySet()) {
             index++;
             if (index == linked.size()) {
                return key;
             }
              }
              return null;
           }

           private static String getFirstKey(Map<String, List<Integer>> linked) {
              for (String key : linked.keySet()) {
             return key;
              }
              return null;
           }
        }
```

Comment: Can you maybe add explanation to your answer, to explain what do you have do different/ what do you add or remove.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) which has `firstKey()` and `lastKey()` methods

Comment: ConcurrentSkipListMap requires a comparator (or natural comparator), so you need to do extra work to save the order in which entries are put.

Comment: HashMap and specifically LinkedHashMap provides access in average of O(1) - contrary to a SkipList, which provides access in average of O(logn).

Comment: "The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys"

Answer (score 0):

Yea I came across the same problem, but luckily I only need the first element... - This is what I did for it.

```
private String getDefaultPlayerType()
{
    String defaultPlayerType = "";
    for(LinkedHashMap.Entry<String,Integer> entry : getLeagueByName(currentLeague).getStatisticsOrder().entrySet())
    {
        defaultPlayerType = entry.getKey();
        break;
    }
    return defaultPlayerType;
}
```

If you need the last element as well - I'd look into how to reverse the order of your map - store it in a temp variable, access the first element in the reversed map(therefore it would be your last element), kill the temp variable.

Here's some good answers on how to reverse order a hashmap:

[How to iterate hashmap in reverse order in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596132/how-to-iterate-hashmap-in-reverse-order-in-java)

If you use help from the above link, please give them up-votes :)
Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

right, you have to manually enumerate keyset till the end of the linkedlist, then retrieve the entry by key and return this entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<Fragment> pullToBackStack() {
    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Map.Entry<String, Fragment>> entryList = new ArrayList<>(backMap.entrySet());
    int size = entryList.size();
    if (size > 0) {
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {// last Fragments
            fragments.add(entryList.get(i).getValue());
            backMap.remove(entryList.get(i).getKey());
        }
        return fragments;
    }
    return null;
}
```