# How can I move a particular HashMap entry to the end of the map?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

How to move a particular `HashMap` entry to the last position?

For example, I have `HashMap` values like this:

```java
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

// map = {Not-Specified 1, test 2, testtest 3};
```

"Not-Specified" may come in any position. it may come first or in the middle of the map. But I want to move the "Not-Specified" to the last position.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain, why you want to do this? Maybe using a HashMap is not the best solution to your problem.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936462/java-linkedhashmap-get-first-or-last-entry

Answer (score 168, accepted):

To answer your question in one sentence:

**Per default, Maps don't have a last entry, it's not part of their contract.**

---

And a side note: it's good practice to code against interfaces, not the implementation classes (see [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Chapter 8, Item 52: **Refer to objects by their interfaces**).

So your declaration should read:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

(All maps share a common contract, so the client need not know what kind of map it is, unless he specifies a sub interface with an extended contract).

---

### Possible Solutions

#### Sorted Maps:

There is a sub interface [SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) that extends the map interface with order-based lookup methods and it has a sub interface [NavigableMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) that extends it even further. The standard implementation of this interface, [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), allows you to sort entries either by natural ordering (if they implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface) or by a supplied [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

You can access the last entry through the [lastEntry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastEntry()) method:

```
NavigableMap<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
// add some entries
Entry<String, Integer> lastEntry = map.lastEntry();
```

#### Linked maps:

There is also the special case of [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), a HashMap implementation that stores the order in which keys are inserted. There is however no interface to back up this functionality, nor is there a  direct way to access the last key. You can only do it through tricks such as using a List in between:

```
Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
// add some entries
List<Entry<String,Integer>> entryList =
    new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
Entry<String, Integer> lastEntry =
    entryList.get(entryList.size()-1);
```

#### Proper Solution:

Since you don't control the insertion order, you should go with the NavigableMap interface, i.e. you would write a comparator that positions the `Not-Specified` entry last.

Here is an example:

```
final NavigableMap<String,Integer> map = 
        new TreeMap<String, Integer>(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(final String o1, final String o2) {
        int result;
        if("Not-Specified".equals(o1)) {
            result=1;
        } else if("Not-Specified".equals(o2)) {
            result=-1;
        } else {
            result =o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
        return result;
    }

});
map.put("test", Integer.valueOf(2));
map.put("Not-Specified", Integer.valueOf(1));
map.put("testtest", Integer.valueOf(3));
final Entry<String, Integer> lastEntry = map.lastEntry();
System.out.println("Last key: "+lastEntry.getKey()
         + ", last value: "+lastEntry.getValue());
```

Output:

> Last key: Not-Specified, last value: 1

#### Solution using HashMap:

If you must rely on HashMaps, there is still a solution, using a) a modified version of the above comparator, b) a [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) initialized with the Map's [entrySet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) and c) the [Collections.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) helper method:

```
    final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("test", Integer.valueOf(2));
    map.put("Not-Specified", Integer.valueOf(1));
    map.put("testtest", Integer.valueOf(3));

    final List<Entry<String, Integer>> entries =
        new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>(){

        public int compareKeys(final String o1, final String o2){
            int result;
            if("Not-Specified".equals(o1)){
                result = 1;
            } else if("Not-Specified".equals(o2)){
                result = -1;
            } else{
                result = o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(final Entry<String, Integer> o1,
            final Entry<String, Integer> o2){
            return this.compareKeys(o1.getKey(), o2.getKey());
        }

    });

    final Entry<String, Integer> lastEntry =
        entries.get(entries.size() - 1);
    System.out.println("Last key: " + lastEntry.getKey() + ", last value: "
        + lastEntry.getValue());

}
```

Output:

> Last key: Not-Specified, last value: 1

Comment: Why would implementing the comparable interface and then using a TreeMap not be your first choice? You seem to know more about Maps than I do, so just wondering

Comment: @nixxbb it *is* my first choice, that's why it appears directly after the literal answer

Comment: oh, I see, you are talking about Comparable vs Comparator. In the OP's case, the keys are Strings, but he requires a custom order. That's why. Otherwise I'd agree with you

Comment: Oh, I see. Very nicely done. Thank you for the reply, I learned a lot just from your answer...

Answer (score 19):

HashMap doesn't have *"the last position"*, as it is not sorted.

You may use other `Map` which implements `java.util.SortedMap`, most popular one is `TreeMap`.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936462/java-linkedhashmap-get-first-or-last-entry

Answer (score 5):

A `SortedMap` is the logical/best choice, however another option is to use a `LinkedHashMap` which maintains two order modes, most-recently-added goes last, and most-recently-accessed goes last. See the Javadocs for more details.

Answer (score 2):

When using numbers as the key, I suppose you could also try this:

```
        Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(4L, "The First");
        map.put(6L, "The Second");
        map.put(11L, "The Last");

        long lastKey = 0;
        //you entered Map<Long, String> entry
        for (Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            lastKey = entry.getKey();
        }
        System.out.println(lastKey); // 11
```

Answer (score 1):

move does not make sense for a hashmap since its a dictionary with a hashcode for bucketing based on key and then a linked list for colliding hashcodes resolved via equals.
Use a TreeMap for sorted maps and then pass in a custom comparator.

Comment: you can't "pass in a custom comparator" with a TreeMap after creation. You can only use it as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario last used key is usually known so it can be used for accessing last value (inserted with the one):

```
class PostIndexData {
    String _office_name;
    Boolean _isGov;
    public PostIndexData(String name, Boolean gov) {
        _office_name = name;
        _isGov = gov;
    }
}
//-----------------------
class KgpData {
    String _postIndex;
    PostIndexData _postIndexData;
    public KgpData(String postIndex, PostIndexData postIndexData) {
        _postIndex = postIndex;
        _postIndexData = postIndexData;;
    }
}

public class Office2ASMPro {
    private HashMap<String,PostIndexData> _postIndexMap = new HashMap<>();
    private HashMap<String,KgpData> _kgpMap = new HashMap<>();
...
private void addOffice(String kgp, String postIndex, String officeName, Boolean gov) {
            if (_postIndexMap.get(postIndex) == null) {
                _postIndexMap.put(postIndex, new PostIndexData(officeName, gov));
            }
            _kgpMap.put( kgp, new KgpData(postIndex, _postIndexMap.get(postIndex)) );
        }
```

Comment: Hi Mad Calm, remember to try to keep your examples concise and simple so anyone reading the question/answer can easily understand. Pasting code without much explanation usually is not a good idea :-) 
Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` explicitly does not define a key order.  Per the class [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

A number other map types do define a key order, including [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and maps which implement the [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface.  Java 21 introduced the [`SequencedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html) interface for maps such as these which have a a well-defined encounter order.

Per [its Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html), a `SequencedMap` is:

> A `Map` that has a well-defined encounter order, that supports operations at both ends, and that is reversible.

One of the operations on `SequencedMap` is [`putLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html#putLast(K,V)).  This optional operation, for `SequencedMap` types that support it, inserts an entry at the end of the map, or moves it to the end if the key is already present.  `LinkedHashMap` supports this method, but `SortedMap` does not.  Per [the method Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html#putLast(K,V)):

> Inserts the given mapping into the map if it is not already present, or replaces the value of a mapping if it is already present (optional operation). After this operation completes normally, the given mapping will be present in this map, and it will be the last mapping in this map's encounter order.

## Scenario in question

Applying the above to your scenario in question, we get:

```java
LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();

populateMap(map); // Populate the map as: {Not-Specified 1, test 2, testtest 3};

map.putLast("Not-Specified", map.get("Not-Specified"));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Find missing all elements from array
        int[] array = {3,5,7,8,2,1,32,5,7,9,30,5};
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            map.put(array[i], 1);
        }
        int maxSize = map.lastKey();
        for(int j=0;j<maxSize;j++) {
            if(null == map.get(j))
                System.out.println("Missing `enter code here`No:"+j);
        }
```

Comment: Find missing all the elements from the array

Comment: This doesn't look to have much to do with the question that was asked.