# Get the last value in map

Tags: java, dictionary

How can i get the last and first key/value of a Map?
For example:

```
Map<String,Integer> ret = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

And this is ret's value:

```
{33=1, 12=2, 21=2, 93=2, 48=9, 68=10}
```

Comment: A `HashMap` isn't ordered, so 'first' and 'last' don't really mean anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the last entry in a Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527216/accessing-the-last-entry-in-a-map)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks :) I was just writing up an answer with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it with `HashMap` because keys are not ordered. Consider using [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

You can get last element using this method:

```
public <K,V> Map.Entry<K,V> getLast(LinkedHashMap<K,V> map) {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    Map.Entry<K, V> result = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        result = iterator.next();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A `HashMap` is an unordered map, so it doesn't have any concept of 'first' or 'last.
If you want a map that retains things in insertion order, you can use a `LinkedHashMap`, and then iterate its `entrySet()` method to pick the first and last values.
You could also use the `SortedMap` interface ([`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) impl.) which orders inserted entries by the natural ordering of keys (or a provided `Comparator`).

Comment: *which orders inserted entries by key size* by key size??? I'd rephrase that. +1 for the rest

Comment: from the TreeMap javadocs: "The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time". There's nothing about the key size there

Comment: K, fixed. size is the natural ordering of ints, which were the keys in the OP's example.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible (or more like doesn't make sense) to differentiate between "first" and "last" when it comes to `HashMap`. If you want to preserve insertion order, you might want to use `LinkedHashMap<K,V>`. But then again, you should elaborate your question to let us know the exact use case demanding this.

Answer (score 1):

since there is no defined order you will basically get a random element if you are unlucky.

else you could go the way HashMap -> getEntrySet -> toArray -> get(size-1)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can get the first object from the map via:

```
Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry = map.entrySet().iterator().next();
```

And the last via:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry = null;
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    entry = iter.next();
}
// now you have the "last" item in the map stored in 'entry'
```

But, as has been stated in other answers, this doesn't mean anything with a HashMap. Substitute it with a LinkedHashMap, however, and you can get the first and last inserted pairs out using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html, in which case you could get the first and last key..