# how to access to end element of a map?

Tags: java

I have this method:

```
    public String nodePropertyGenerator(Map<String,Object> properties){
    String prop="";
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
        prop += entry.getKey() + ":'" +entry.getValue()+"' ,";
        Iterator iterator = properties.entrySet().iterator(); 
    }
    return prop;
}
```

I want to this method return a string like this:

```
name:'hossein' , age:'24' , address:'khorram'
```

so I want to check if my map's element be end element , it remove "," from end of string. how to do that. please help me. thanks

Comment: `return prop.replaceAll(",$", "");`  ??

Comment: [Refer this one, this might solve your problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527216/accessing-the-last-entry-in-a-map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to add a `boolean` variable, set it to `true` before entering the loop, and use it to decide if you need a comma *before* adding the next component, like this:

```
boolean isFirst = true;
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
    if (!isFirst) {
        res.append(", ");
    }
    isFirst = false;
    res.append(entry.getKey());
    res.append(":'");
    res.append(entry.getValue());
    res.append("'");
}
```

Note that using the concatenation operator on immutable strings in a loop is inefficient. You should use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: it worked . thanks my friend. I'm happy for your help.good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell whether the current iteration is the last one. I suggest you use a `StringBuilder` instead of repeated string concatenation, then just trim the length at the end:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
    builder.append(entry.getKey())
           .append(":'")
           .append(entry.getValue())
           .append("' ,");
}
if (builder.length() > 0) {
    builder.setLength(builder.length() - 2);
}
return builder.toString();
```

Comment: A touch faster. :) +1

Comment: Shouldn't that be `builder.length() - 2`?

Comment: @tobias_k: Whoops, yes, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 has a class to do this: [java.util.StringJoiner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

You would use it like this:

```
StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner("' ,");
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
    stringJoiner.add(entry.getKey() + ":'" +entry.getValue());
}
return stringJoiner.toString();
```

Or alternatively you could use a `Stream` to do this:

```
return properties.entrySet().stream()
                 .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + ":'" +entry.getValue())
                 .collect(Collectors.joining("' ,"));
```