# Getting value of last Hashmap key

Tags: java, hashmap

How to get value of last HashMap key?

```
Map<Integer, Employee> map = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
map.put(1, "FIRST INSERTED");
map.put(2, "SECOND INSERTED");
map.put(3,"THIRD INSERTED");
```

What I want to do is take value of last key (3), increment it and add another row with next number (4).

Comment: Iterate till last. and then add. But HashMap doesn't guarantee same order of insertion while iterating over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a normal HashMap for that, you need another member of the "collections" family; in thise case, its cousin **LinkedHashMap**. That one keeps the order in which elements were added. Keep in mind that those two different maps do show different behavior regarding "cost" of insert/delete/iterating operations.

Answer (score 3):

**Maps don't have a last entry, it's not part of their contract.**

Neither **HashMap** maintains insertion order.

Try using [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), and access the last entry

```
    NavigableMap<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    map.lastEntry().getKey()
```

There is also `LinkedHashMap` that maintains the order in which keys are inserted. There is however no interface to back up this functionality, nor is there a direct way to access the last key.

PS : Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527216/accessing-the-last-entry-in-a-map)

Answer (score 0):

A `HashMap` does not guarantee any order. If by "last key" you mean "max key", you should rather find maximum of the `Set<Integer>` returned by `map.keySet()`.

OR use another type of `Map` (`NavigableMap` for example) as suggested by other answers.