# retrieve last n items from map of items java

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

I have a `map` and I would like to retrieve the last **50 items** inserted onto the `map` or items added to the `map` in the last **2 seconds** (whichever greater) ..

What's the most efficient way I can do that?

```
Map<Date, Book> books = new HashMap<Date, Book>();
```

Notes:
- I want to maximize throughput and minimize latency.
- I want to run on the JVM and minimize heap footprint.

Comment: You can make use of TreeMap or similar data structure that keeps the order.

Comment: And if you are building an application, I would recommend storing all the data into db and run a query to fetch data either by date or last 50 items.

Comment: @zenwraight I am not allowed to use a external db..

Comment: TreeMap maintains order in sorted order but I want to maintain last insertion order..

Comment: And you have to do it using only hashmap or u can use some other data structure also ?

Comment: @zenwraight, TreeMap would not preserve insertion order and LinkedHashMap will preserve the order but in this case, I think stack would be a better option to store the keys.

Comment: @suvojit_007 I can use any other data structure..

Comment: @KshitijRoshan as mentioned in the answer, I feel Stack will do ur work , or Queue, something around that line.

Comment: I agree @suvojit_007 stack will do.

Comment: Thank you guys.. very helpful!

Comment: _last 50 items_ - Do you mean last by `Date`, the key of `Map<Date, Book> book`?

Comment: This may be related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527216/accessing-the-last-entry-in-a-map

Comment: @LuCio last items by date..

Comment: I would highly recommend using a Priority queue. Pass your comparator object to the queue which sorts the books by date and then filter out the dequeued objects by the time constraint.

Comment: I want to maximize throughput and minimize latency.I want to run on the JVM and minimize heap footprint.

Comment: Are the keys the date/time of insertion into the map?

Comment: Yes! The keys can be anything though, I assigned date as the keys as it made more sense to me..

Answer (score 2):

Use a **stack** to store the `Date` and then pop items as a key from the stack.
Just push `Date` as key whenever you make an entry in **HashMap**.

Comment: I want to maximize throughput and minimize latency.I want to run on the JVM and minimize heap footprint.

Comment: @KshitijRoshan push and pop operation are very much efficient in Stack so I think you should use Stack in this case.

Comment: `Stack` is deprecated (since long ago). Use an `ArrayDeque` instead

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner `LinkedList` can be used too.

Comment: @suvojit_007 Agreed. It can be used too, it's a matter of preference. I think `ArrayDeque` is better for most cases, but in this particular case, `LinkedList` would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in one sentence:

Per default, Maps don't have a last entry, it's not part of their contract. A (Hash)Map Stores the items memory optimized.

Possible Solutions
Sorted Maps:

You can access the last entry through the lastEntry method:

```
NavigableMap<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
// add some entries
Entry<String, Integer> lastEntry = map.lastEntry();
```

Or u use a Linked map:

```
Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
// add some entries
List<Entry<String,Integer>> entryList =
    new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
Entry<String, Integer> lastEntry =
    entryList.get(entryList.size()-1);
```

both are native Java libs.

Comment: `TreeMap.lastEntry()` gives the entry with the largest/smallest key value. Iterating a `LinkedHashMap` backwards should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to get [*last items by date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766912/retrieve-last-n-items-from-map-of-items-java#comment92457068_52766912), thus the key of the `Map<Date, Book> books` you can do the following:

```
  protected static List<Book> getLastXBooks(Map<Date, Book> books, int x) {
    return books.entrySet().stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.<Entry<Date, Book>, Date> comparing(Entry::getKey).reversed())
      .limit(x)
      .map(Entry::getValue)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  protected static List<Book> getBooksOfLastXSeconds(Map<Date, Book> books, int seconds) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long msAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() - seconds * 1000;
    return books.entrySet().stream()
      .filter(e -> e.getKey().getTime() <= now && e.getKey().getTime() >= msAgo)
      .sorted(Comparator.<Entry<Date, Book>, Date> comparing(Entry::getKey).reversed())
      .map(Entry::getValue)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

In `getBooksOfLastXSeconds` I added the sorting to make the result easy to compare. As of the question it isn't necessary.

Let's have an example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Date, Book> books = new HashMap<Date, Book>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      Book book = new Book("Book " + (100 - i));
      books.put(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - i * 100), book);
      System.out.println(book);
    }
    List<Book> last50 = getLastXBooks(books, 50);
    System.out.println(last50); // [Book: Book 100, Book: Book 99, ... Book 51, Book: Book 50]
    List<Book> booksOfLast2Seconds = getBooksOfLastXSeconds(books, 2);
    System.out.println(booksOfLast2Seconds); // [Book: Book 100, Book: Book 99, ... Book 82, Book: Book 81]
  }
```

EDIT
*What's the most efficient way I can do that?*
The most efficient way would be, to have the books already ordered by insertion date. Then it's not necessary to compare all books (do the `sort` above) to get the last 50 books. You could use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the insertion order. The insertion order has to be the [natural order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) of `Date` thus the chronological order.

Comment: I want to maximize throughput and minimize latency.I want to run on the JVM and minimize heap footprint.