# Java Get last key from Hashmap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

previously I apologized if my question is classic. but because I just learned Java programming for android, I didn't really understand the commands.

I'm currently making an application with the code section as follows:

```
Map<Integer, CompTypes> mapCompTypes = new java.util.HashMap();

class CompTypes
{
    int androidId;
    AndroidViewComponent component;
    String text;
    String type;
    CompTypes(int androidId, AndroidViewComponent component, String type, String text)
    {
        this.androidId = androidId;
        this.component = component;
        this.type = type;
        this.text = text;
    }
}

public void SendMessage(HVArrangement container, String message, String dateTime, int fontSize, int fontColor, int alignment, int startid)
{
    int id = Integer.parseInt(ChatBox.this.GetLastId());
    TextBox comp = new TextBox(vertical);
    comp.getView().setId(id);
    comp.Text(message);
    comp.FontSize(fontSize);
    comp.TextColor(fontColor);
    comp.MultiLine(true);
    comp.Enabled(false);
    comp.RequestFocus();
    mapCompTypes.put(Integer.valueOf(id), new CompTypes(id, comp, compType, comp.Text()));

    int id2 = id + 1;
    Label dt = new Label(vertical);
    dt.getView().setId(id2);        
    ((TextView)dt.getView()).setText(android.text.Html.fromHtml(datetime));
    dt.HTMLFormat(true);
    dt.Text(datetime);
    dt.getView().setOnClickListener(this);
    dt.getView().setOnLongClickListener(this);
    mapCompTypes.put(Integer.valueOf(id2), new CompTypes(id2, dt, compType, dt.Text()));
}


public String GetLastId()
{
    // how to get last id?
    //return ids;
}
```

at the moment I'm having trouble getting the value from id as the last id from Hashmap.
I've read a number of questions and answers here that "Maps don't have the last entry, it's not part of their contract."
is there another way to get the last id?

Comment: A `HashMap` doesn't have a "last" key, either by insertion order or by sort order. What exactly do you mean by "last"?

Comment: This will help you to find out your needs:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527216/accessing-the-last-entry-in-a-map?

Comment: Since you're are looking for to get the last id, use "LinkedHashMap" (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) It is exactly like HashMap, except that when you iterate over it, it presents the items in the insertion order. In this case you can get the last id.

Comment: Why do you want to use `HashMap` instead of `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 6):

`HaspMap` doesn't preserve order.So,Its not possible to get any element via position either last, first or middle.

One thing you can do is that save your `key` in some variable when do insertion in `HashMap` and access that variable to get key of your last object. For guarantee order you can also looked for [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: Note that LinkedHashMaps have 2 ordering modes-  FIFO and LRU.  Make sure its in FIFO when you use it.

Answer (score 3):

HashMap doesn't maintain ordering.
If you want to maintain insertion ordering then use LinkedHashMap. It can be used like this.

```
 private static String getLastId() {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put(1, "A");
        map.put(2, "B");
        map.put(3, "C");
        String lastObject = "";
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            lastObject = entry.getValue();
        }
        return lastObject;
    }
```

If you have map key as natural ordering. Then you can use TreeMap or pass a comparator to TreeMap. Here is an snippet to do that.

```
private static String getLastId() {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
    map.put(1, "A");
    map.put(2, "B");
    map.put(3, "C");
    return ((TreeMap<Integer, String>) map).lastEntry().getValue();
}
```

See documentation here of [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you **increase `id`** as key for the map. So to get your **last id** you have two options:

- Use `LinkedHashMap`, then get all keys and get the last one
- Use `TreeMap` with *reverse order comparator*, then get the first key (this one will be with highes value, i.e. the last).

---

```
Map<Integer, CompTypes> mapCompTypes = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());

final class CompTypes {
    private final int androidId;
    private final AndroidViewComponent component;
    private final String text;
    private final String type;

    CompTypes(AndroidViewComponent component, String type)  {
        this.androidId = component.getView().getId();
        this.component = component;
        this.type = type;
        this.text = component.Text();
    }
}

public void SendMessage(HVArrangement container, String message, String datetime, int fontSize, int fontColor, int alignment, int startid) {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(ChatBox.this.GetLastId());
    mapCompTypes.put(id, new CompTypes(createCompTypes(createTextBox(id, message, fontSize, fontColor)), compType));
    mapCompTypes.put(id + 1, new CompTypes(createLabel(id, datetime)));
}

private CompTypes createCompTypes(AndroidViewComponent component) {
    return new CompTypes(component, compType)
}

private TextBox createTextBox(int id, String message, int fontSize, int fontColor) {
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox(vertical);
    textBox.getView().setId(id);
    textBox.Text(message);
    textBox.FontSize(fontSize);
    textBox.TextColor(fontColor);
    textBox.MultiLine(true);
    textBox.Enabled(false);
    textBox.RequestFocus();
    return textBox;
}

private Label createLabel(int id, String datetime) {
    Label label = new Label(vertical);
    label.getView().setId(id);        
    ((TextView)dt.getView()).setText(android.text.Html.fromHtml(datetime));
    label.HTMLFormat(true);
    label.Text(datetime);
    label.getView().setOnClickListener(this);
    label.getView().setOnLongClickListener(this);
    return label;
}

public String GetLastId() {
    int lastId = mapCompTypes.isEmpty() ? -1 : mapCompTypes.keySet().iterator().next();
    //return ids;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a TreeMap instead where you can make use of lastEntry() method.

```
Map<Integer, CompTypes> mapCompTypes = new TreeMap();
mapCompTypes.lastEntry()
```

Comment: doesnot gurantee in HM, only LHM