# Getting last key from a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have `LinkedHashMap` returning from DB. From this map I need to get the last key. If I get all keys using `keySet` method it returns `Set` of keys but `Set` does not guarantee the order. I need to take exactly last key from the `LinkedHashMap` returned from DB. How can I do that ?

Below is the code how I get data from database.

```java
LinkedHashMap<String,String> map = someDao.getMap(String input);
```

From this map I need to take last key.

Comment: The last element in which order? Lexicographic?

Comment: As you said, there is no ordering on sets (hence the name). How do you define *last* if you have no ordering? The one with the highest `hashCode()` value? Or, the one you put into the map? Or, the one which is in the *deepest* bin?

Comment: Hi rlegendi, Thanks for your reply. i need the one which is in the deepest bin.

Comment: @rlegendi: Although sets don't *generally* support ordering, several *implementations* do. `LinkedHashMap` maintains insertion order, so I'd *expect* its key and value sets to do likewise.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, true, sry, I forgot we are speaking of a `LinkedHashMap`. Surely, `SortedSet` implementations support ordering, but I saw not that was used. The ordering of a `LinkedHashMap` might also trick you if an existing element is put into it again (it will be not re-inserted).

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936462/java-linkedhashmap-get-first-or-last-entry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`keySet()` being executed on `LinkedHashMap` returns `LinkedHashSet` that is indeed `Set` but "remembers" the order of elements.

You can get the last element as following:

```
Map<TheType> map = .....
.................
TheType theLastKey = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet()).get(map.size() - 1)
```

Comment: There are better ways to get the last value of an iterable - ways which *don't* take O(n) space. See Guava's Iterables.getLast for example.

Comment: Good point, @Jon Skeet. But I wrapped set with `ArrayList` that does not have such problem.

Comment: Well the code you've given won't even compile, but if it were `new ArrayList<TheType>(map.getKeys())` then it *would* exhibit that problem - because that constructor copies all the elements.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you post a link to a better solution or just post an Answer? I don't see 'Guava's Iterables.getLast' :(

Comment: @kilaka: If you search for Guava Iterables I'm sure you'll find it.

Comment: As I see it, Iterables#getLast  calls Iterators#getLast method in case of LinkedHashSet, so that O(n) is guaranteed...  LinkedHashSet is not SortedSet

Answer (score 1):

The last entry of a `LinkedHashMap` can be easily accessed using the [`lastEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html#lastEntry()) method which was added in Java 21.  The last key can be retrieved from this `Entry`.

```java
LinkedHashMap<String,String> map = someDao.getMap(String input);

Entry<String,String> lastValue = map.lastEntry();
String lastKey = lastEntry.getKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from a different post helped me with this answer. Pls refer
[Java HashMap: How to get a key and value by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973512/java-hashmap-how-to-get-the-first-keys-value) for the original post.

```
Object myKey = myHashMap.keySet().toArray()[0];
```

where i have replaced the 0

```
toArray()[0]  - (where 0 represents the first item in the keyset)
```

with the size of the keyset

```
toArray()[(keyset().size)-1]
```

Note : Without the -1 at the end, you would get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.