# Iterating through a LinkedHashMap in reverse order

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, RecordItemElement>
```

that I need to iterate through from a given key's position, backwards. So if I was given the 10th item's key, I'd need iterate backwards through the hashmap 9, 8, 7 etc.

Comment: Do you know the keys of all items or not ?

Comment: I do. Suggesting I iterate through once, add to a list, then iterate that backwards using them as keys? Suppose that would work

Comment: I assume you just want to iterate in reverse in "order of insertion" here, or do you want real ordering based on some natural ordering? See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1936472/32453

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to iterate through it. But it would be handy to pull the keys off and store it in a list. Thats the only way you can do indexOf() type operations.

```
List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
// Given 10th element's key
String key = "aKey";
int idx = keyList.indexOf(key);
for ( int i = idx ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) 
 System.out.println(map.get(keyList.get(i)));
```

Comment: Instead of keyList.indexOf(...) use listIterator with the position. and iterate with previous()

Comment: Instead of keyList.indexOf(...) use keyList.size()-1

Comment: @Kal The operation of your solution is O(n), which is well.. *horrible*.

Comment: Well doing so you create unnecessary overhead by copying the key set. Consider using TreeMap.

Comment: Doesn't a `Set` destroy the order? Consequently, wouldn't `keyList` contain the keys in random order?

Comment: I suppose it works because the documentation says the returned `Set` is backed by the `LinkedHashMap`. Seems flaky though, since there is generally no guarantee on the order of iteration of a `Set`.

Comment: The `LinkedHashMap#keySet()` returns a `Set` backed by a `LinkedKeySet`, which is a nested class with package-local visibility. The iteration order is defined by its `Spliterator`, which is ordered in the same order as the map entries. So, in this case, the order IS guaranteed.

Answer (score 15):

The question requires a LinkedHashMap in reverse order, some answers suggesting using a TreeSet but this will reorder the map based upon the key.

This solution allows the iteration over the original LinkedHashMap not the new ArrayList as has also been proposed:

```
List<String> reverseOrderedKeys = new ArrayList<String>(linkedHashMap.keySet());
Collections.reverse(reverseOrderedKeys);
for (String key : reverseOrderedKeys) {
    RecordItemElement line = linkedHashMap.get(key);
}
```

Comment: I'd personally create a `List<Entry<String, RecordItemElement>>` using `new ArrayList<>(linkedHashMap.entrySet())` and use the entries' keys & values, rather than storing just the keys and doing a second map lookup to get the value for each key.

Answer (score 10):

The HashMap:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Reverse iterating over values:

```
ListIterator<Sprite> iterator = new ArrayList<String>(map.values()).listIterator(map.size());
while (iterator.hasPrevious()) String value = iterator.previous();
```

Reverse iterating over keys:

```
ListIterator<Integer> iterator = new ArrayList(map.keySet()).listIterator(map.size());
while (iterator.hasPrevious()) Integer key = iterator.previous();
```

Reverse iterating over both:

```
ListIterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iterator = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>(map.entrySet()).listIterator(map.size());
while (iterator.hasPrevious()) Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = iterator.previous();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new LinkedList(linkedHashMap.keySet()).descendingIterator();
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 21, `LinkedHashMap` has the [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#reversed()) method, which returns a reversed view of the map.  This can be iterated over in the standard manner.

```java
myLinkedHashMap.reversed().forEach((key, value) -> {
  // Do something with the key and/or value
});
```

To specifically start with a given key as requested, a `Stream` over the reversed map's entry set could be used, using the [`dropWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) method to skip all elements encountered prior to that key:

```java
String matchingKey = "someKey";
myLinkedHashMap.entrySet().stream()
        .dropWhile(e -> !matchingKey.equals(e.getKey()))
        .forEach(e -> {
            String key = e.getKey();
            RecordItemElement value = e.getValue();
            // Do something with key & value
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "user22745008" solution and labdas with some generics you can have a very neat solution as a method:

```
  public static <T, Q> LinkedHashMap<T, Q> reverseMap(LinkedHashMap<T, Q> toReverse)
  {
      LinkedHashMap<T, Q> reversedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      List<T> reverseOrderedKeys = new ArrayList<>(toReverse.keySet());
      Collections.reverse(reverseOrderedKeys);
      reverseOrderedKeys.forEach((key)->reversedMap.put(key,toReverse.get(key)));
      return reversedMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I think it's lacking an answer that takes a newer approach. The following uses Java 9 features:

```
Deque<Map.Entry<String, RecordItemElement>> top = map.entrySet().stream()
        .takeWhile(e -> !givenKey.equals(e.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));
```

The code above streams the map's entryset, keeping entries until a key equal to the given key is found. Then, the entries are collected to an `ArrayDeque`.

One detail is missing, though. Depending on whether you need the entry that matches the given key to also be included in the result or not, you might need to manually add it to the deque. If you don't want it added, then you're done. Otherwise, simply do:

```
top.add(Map.entry(givenKey, map.get(givenKey)));
```

Now, to iterate the `Deque` in reverse order, simply use its `descendingIterator()`:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, RecordItemElement>> descIt = top.descendingIterator();
```

*It's worth mentioning that this approach only works if the stream is **sequential**.* Anyways, we wouldn't have gained anything using a parallel stream here.