# How to traverse Linked Hash Map in reverse?

Tags: java, reverse, linkedhashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterating through a LinkedHashMap in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170871/iterating-through-a-linkedhashmap-in-reverse-order)

How to traverse Linked Hash Map in a reverse order? Is there any predefined method in map to do that?

I'm creating it as follows:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1, "one");
map.put(2, "two");
map.put(3, "three");
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170871/iterating-through-a-linkedhashmap-in-reverse-order

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
List<Entry<Integer,String>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

for( int i = list.size() -1; i >= 0 ; i --){
    Entry<Integer,String> entry = list.get(i);
}
```

Not really pretty and at the cost of a copy of the entry set, which if your map has a significant number of entries might be a problem.

The excellant [Guava library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) have a `[List.reverse(List<>)][2]` that would allow you to use the Java 5 for each style loop rather than the indexed loop:

```
//using guava
for( Entry entry : Lists.reverse(list) ){
    // much nicer
}
```

Comment: Should be `map.entrySet()`.

Answer (score 19):

Try this, it will print the *keys* in reverse insertion order:

```
ListIterator<Integer> iter =
    new ArrayList<>(map.keySet()).listIterator(map.size());

while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
    Integer key = iter.previous();
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

You can also iterate by the reverse insertion order of *entries*:

```
ListIterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iter =
    new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet()).listIterator(map.size());

while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = iter.previous();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as the list iterator starts are the beginning of the list thus iter.hasPrevious() will be false on the very first call

Comment: @GarethDavis you're wrong, the above list iterator starts at the _end_ of the list - that's what `listIterator(map.size())` does.

Comment: listIterator is overloaded,one with no argument and one with position argument.listIterator() is same as listIterator(0)

Comment: You might modify the first line to:  ListIterator<Integer> iter =
    new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet()).listIterator(map.size());  for type safety reasons.  Thank you for this answer, it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Guava RULES:

```
List<Object> reverseList = Lists.reverse(
        Lists.newArrayList(map.keySet()));
```

[Lists.reverse](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29)