# Change LinkedHashMap items in reverse order

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I would like to change the elements in my LinkedHashMap in the reverse order. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("Hello", 2);
    map.put("World", 1);
    reverse(map);
    System.out.println(map);// {Wordl=1, Hello=2}
}

public static void reverse(Map<String, Integer> map){
   // Reverse my map...
}
```

But I did not find anything that could help me to do this. Can someone suggest how this can be solved? 
Thank.

Comment: @Jabongg I don't think this is what OP needs, he needs something that produces `{Hello=2, Wordl=1}` I think...

Comment: @Jabongg - That Q&A is about creating an inverse map.   This is not a dup of that one.

Comment: Yaah! you are right. it's about reversing the whole map. Thanks Stephen C @A4L

Comment: @Jabongg, In this issue are swapped keys and values. I have another question.

Comment: Yaah! I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to iterate in reverse order:

```
   ListIterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet()).listIterator(map.size());
            while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iterator.previous();
                System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            }
```

Comment: @StasUmanets Your welcome, Don't forget vote up!

Comment: Since Java 7, you can write `new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet())` instead of `new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet())`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here:

[How to traverse Linked Hash Map in reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893231/how-to-traverse-linked-hash-map-in-reverse#8893397)

Check out the second answer which offers options on how to traverse.
Also see the link to the Guava library.

Comment: Ok, i will check Guava library.

Answer (score 0):

// You can do take use of Arraylist. Here's an implementation.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Hello", "2");
    map.put("World", "1");
    // create an arraylist initialized with keys of map
    ArrayList keyList = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
    for (int i = keyList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // get key
        String key = (String) keyList.get(i);
        System.out.println("Key :: " + key);
        // get value corresponding to key
        String value = map.get(key);
        System.out.println("Value :: " + value);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.