# How to iterate hashmap in reverse order in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying this for some hour but not finding any best approach to achieve iteration of hashmap in reverse order, this is the hashmap I have.

```
      Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

             for(Integer key : map.keySet()) {
                List<String> value = map.get(key);
                List<Map<String,?>> security = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
                for(int ixy = 0; ixy < value.size()-1; ixy++){
                    security.add(createItem(value.get(ixy), value.get(ixy+1))); 
                }
                adapter.addSection(Integer.toString(key), new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), security, R.layout.list_complex, new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));  
            }
```

I have seen example of TreeMap as well,

```
             Map<Integer, List<String>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>(map);
```

But treemap also gives in ascending order, what I want is in descending order.

Comment: HashMaps don't have orders, so they don't have reverse orders either.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170871/iterating-through-a-linkedhashmap-in-reverse-order

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hashmap does not have specific order. But you can use TreeMap.

Perhaps this simple example can help you :

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
        map.put(1, "abc1");
        map.put(2, "abc2");
        map.put(3, "abc3");

        ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());
        for(int i=keys.size()-1; i>=0;i--){
            System.out.println(map.get(keys.get(i)));
        }
```

Comment: Note that this method is rather inefficient both in terms of memory usage and time complexity.

Comment: NPE's answer seems much more appropriate, since it does not require the space/time required to create the ArrayList`

Comment: I don't like this because it depends on an integer value in the key space. I actually prefer JB Nizet's answer of reversing the default sorting order, that way, regardless of the type of value in your key space, you can just iterate over the keys.

Answer (score 50):

> best approach to acheive iteration of hashmap in reverse order

`HashMap` does not define any particular ordering of its element. Therefore the "reverse" order isn't defined either.

For a `TreeMap`, you can use [`descendingMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingMap%28%29).

Comment: Or its Java 21 equivalent, [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html#reversed()).

Answer (score 15):

A HashMap doesn't maintain eny order between keys.

A TreeMap orders its keys by their natural order, or by the order imposed by a comparator that you pass when constructing the map. So if you want to have Integer keys ordered in reverse order, construct the TreeMap this way:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> sortedMap = 
    new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Good approach as well, though I find `TreeMap#descendingMap()` more elegant. U_U

Answer (score 6):

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>(Collections.reverseOrder());

Collections.reverseOrder() keeps the map sorted in descending order.
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `TreeMap#descendingKeySet` method.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();

for(Integer key : map.descendingKeySet()) {
    List<String> value = map.get(key);
    List<Map<String,?>> security = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
    for(int ixy = 0; ixy < value.size()-1; ixy++){
        security.add(createItem(value.get(ixy), value.get(ixy+1))); 
    }
    adapter.addSection(Integer.toString(key), new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), security, R.layout.list_complex, new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));
}
```

**Reference**:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingKeySet--

Answer (score 4):

You can't iterate over a `HashMap` in reverse because of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

What you should use is a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a
>   doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked
>   list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in
>   which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that
>   insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map.
>   (A key k is reinserted into a map m if m.put(k, v) is invoked when
>   m.containsKey(k) would return true immediately prior to the
>   invocation.)

Comment: unfortunately even the JDK LinkedHashMap doesn't have easy access to its internal double linked list to allow you to traverse in "reverse order" so I guess you'd basically have to "roll you own" (linked list with HashMap combined) class, unfortunately. Guava might have something that helps...

Comment: unfortunately even the JDK LinkedHashMap doesn't have easy access to its internal double linked list to allow you to traverse in "reverse order" see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1936472/32453

Answer (score 4):

The hashmap is not an ordered collection. Use TreeMap instead, which has descendingKeySet for reverse iteration. See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is also a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

```
    TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(1, "abc1");
    map.put(2, "abc2");
    map.put(3, "abc3");
    NavigableMap<Integer, String> nmap = map.descendingMap();
    for (NavigableMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry : nmap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

An implementation of NPE idea.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you need a [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#descendingMap%28%29), like a TreeMap.

Answer (score 2):

> But treemap also gives in asecding order, what i want is in descending order.

Implement a `Comparator` that will compare it reverse than natural order and then just iterate normally you will have reverse iteration

Answer (score 2):

Use insted:

```
new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder())
```

and you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the Iterators obtained from Java Hashtable via:
Hashtable.values().iterator() and Hashtable.keys().asIterator()
are both in reverse order by default. One oddity, The values().iterator has a first final value of "0" which I didn't add when populating it.