# Traverse values of Hash map key an value in decreasing order or increasing order?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to traverse a Hash map in decreasing order or in increasing order but I am not getting the proper output.

Here is my map:

```
Hashmap<String Integer> hm= new Hashmap<String,Integer>();
```

Here are my values:

```
Key    Value
Hi     4
kumar  1
Hello  1
vivek  3
```

I am trying something like:

```
List<Integer> ValueList = new ArrayList<Integer>(hm.values());
                ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(hm.keySet());

Collections.sort(ValueList);
                Collections.reverse(keyList);
                Collections.reverse(ValueList);
```

and I want this something like:

```
Key    Value
kumar  1
Hello  1
vivek  3
Hi     4
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: i have updated my code what i am trying

Comment: You want to sort your hashmap based on numerical values?

Comment: yes  but  i dont want to use that newmeric value as a key  because there could be some duplicate  value there

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: HashMap is not meant to store elements in ascending or descending order. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10596272/4454454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/userguide.html) `ListOrderedMap`. Here's the solution:

```
//Populate the map
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Hi", 4);
map.put("kumar", 1);
map.put("Hello", 1);
map.put("vivek", 3);

//Sort the values
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
Collections.sort(values);

int size = values.size();
Set<Entry<String, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet();

//Create a new ordered map
ListOrderedMap<String, Integer> orderedMap;
orderedMap = ListOrderedMap.listOrderedMap(new HashMap<String, Integer>(map));

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    Integer value = values.get(i);
    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iter = entries.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, Integer> entry = iter.next();
        if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
            //Put all values at index i that match the value
            orderedMap.put(i, entry.getKey(), value);
        }
    }
}

//Print the orderedMap key/value pairs
entries = orderedMap.entrySet();
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : entries) {
    final String key = entry.getKey();
    final Integer value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("key = " + key + ", value = " + value);
}
```

Output:

```
key = Hello, value = 1
key = kumar, value = 1
key = vivek, value = 3
key = Hi, value = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view a Map as a set of entries, where each entry has a key and a value. So what you want is a sorted list of entries. You can't just sort keys or values, as you would lose the association between the key and the value:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
entries.sort(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access these values often, you can avoid the sort by using a `TreeMap` object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

This special `Map` can be used like a normal `HashMap` with the additional feature that it will sort your keys automatically using their `Comparable`, `Equals` and `Hash` methods (which you have to `override`)

If you define your own Key Class, you can make it so it will sort your values automatically.

If you don't need this performance boost, extracting the values then sorting them with `Collections.sort` works well too.