# Most convenient way to get the last key or value in a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, key, linkedhashmap

`LinkedHashMap` description says "it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries" so I'm wondering how to get the last entry or key entered? Can I confidently downcast `.values()` to `LinkedList` to get that doubly-linked list and use `.getLast()` of that? Or is it an instance of some other Java collection?

I want to stick with `java.util` if possible.

Comment: The method `values()` does not return a `List<>` view or a `LinkedList<>` view; rather it returns a `Collection<>` view. The actual type returned is an instance of a private class called `Values` that extends `AbstractCollection<>`.

Comment: You could make a custom class that will store the last element entered...

Comment: bdares, would you like to put this comment as an answer? It's my fave and I'll accept it as the answer if you do.

Comment: Seems impossible with java.util (without reflection) but see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1936472/32453

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the last element.  But you'll have to look at the suggestions from others to get the last element of the `Collection<V>` returned by `values()`.

I checked in the source code that the returned values are indeed in the expected order:
The `AbstactCollection<V>` returned by `LinkedListMap.values()` is backed by an `Iterator<V>` over the values which is itself directly linked to the `Iterator<K>` over the keys.  And obviously the `Iterator<K>` over the keys is implemented with the **ordered** doubly linked list.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that nothing in the documentation suggests iteration over a LinkedHashMap's values are guaranteed to respect the insertion order of the map.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, you cannot.

The "maintained doubly-linked list" is not any java.util.LinkedList type or other collection. It's manually implemented in LinkedHashMap and LinkedHashMap.Entry classes.

You can only build `LinkedList` from `values()` and then use `letLast()` :

```
Foo last = new LinkedList<Foo>(myLinkedHashMap.values()).getLast();
```

Comment: `letLast()` => did you mean `getLast()` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** My previous answer was wrong. You cannot do it without modifying the default behaviour! See below why.

---

> **..how to get the last entry or key entered?**

From the API description of `LinkedHashMap` you can read:

> A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings or, in the case of access-ordered linked hash maps, affects iteration order. In ***insertion-ordered*** linked hash maps, merely changing the value associated with a key that is already contained in the map is not a structural modification. In ***access-ordered*** linked hash maps, merely querying the map with get is a structural modification.

So what does it all mean?

- ***access-ordered***  - every time you do a `put` or a `get` the order of the elements changes
- ***insertion-ordered*** - when inserting elements (for the first time) they are added last

For example:

```
map.put(1, 1); 
map.put(2, 2); 
map.put(1, 10);
System.out.println(map);
```

... will print `{1=10, 2=2}` with *insertion-ordered* and `{2=2, 1=10}` with *access-ordered'. The trouble is using `access-ordered` if of course if you do a `get` operations the order also changes.

---

### How to fix

So... how to fix. Well the `LinkedHashMap` cannot be used directly used. So you can wrap it (do not care about the corny name) and override the `put` and the `putAll` methods so that they remove the key from the map first before putting it back in!

```
class BestLinkedHashMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V last = super.remove(key);
        super.put(key, value);
        return last;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for (K key : m.keySet())
            super.remove(key);

        super.putAll(m);
    }
}
```

---

Then to get the last element, either do:

- wrap the output from in a `LinkedList` implementation:

  ```
  V v = new LinkedList<V>(map.values()).getLast();
  ```
- `toArray()` way:

  ```
  Collection<V> values = map.values();
  V v = values.toArray(new V[0])[values.size() - 1];
  ```
- iterate to the last element using the iterator:

  ```
  Iterator<V> it = values.iterator();
  V last = null;
  while (it.hasNext())
      last = it.next();
  ```

Comment: This solution traverses over all the values instead of getting it in O(1) - as should be if it's a double-linked list.

Answer (score 0):

I have "extended" the Jdk LinkedHashMap to allow that, you can take a look at: [LinkedHashMapEx.java](https://github.com/zolyfarkas/spf4j/blob/master/spf4j-core/src/main/java/org/spf4j/ds/LinkedHashMapEx.java)