# Method that accepts String and tokenizes it and puts each word in arraylist and prints in reverse..?

Tags: java, arrays, string, tokenize

Basically I wrote out the code but I don't know how to write it in reverse.
Question asks: 
Write a method that accepts a String and tokenizes it. put each word into an array and print the array in reverse.

Here's the code

```js
public void tokens(String s)
{
 String tokenArray[] = s.split("X");

 for (String s:tokenArray)
  System.out.println(s);

}  (don't have to do number 8)
```

Comment: new StringBuilder(the_string_variable).reverse().toString()

Comment: do you want java for-each reverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use a simple for loop starting at the end of the array like this:

```
for(int i=tokenArray.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
     System.out.println(tokenArray[i]);
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed. I will accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Noah Thanks! Glad to help ;) Hit the little check mark so I get some points! :P

Comment: I got more questions if need any more points so let me know lol

Comment: lol, okay well I can probably help you, as you long as you attempt it yourself first, otherwise you won't learn! ;)

Answer (score 0):

A for loop can go forward

```
for ( int i = 0; i < lengthOfSomething; i++ ){....}
```

and reverse

```
for ( int i = lengthOfSomething-1; i >= 0; i-- ){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
for( int i = sizeOfTokenArray -1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
    System.out.println( tokenArray[i] );
```

#### for each

You can also view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098117/can-one-do-a-for-each-loop-in-java-in-reverse-order) page for reverse for-each

#### recursive functions

you can also use recursive function but not recommended

```
public static void reversePrint( String [] arges , int index ){
    if( index > arges.length() )
        return;
    reversePrint( arges , ++index );
    System.out.println( arges[ index ] );
}

public static void print( String [] arges , int index ){
    if( index > arges.length() )
        return;
    System.out.println( arges[ index ] );
    print( arges , ++index );
}
// use them
public static void main( String [] arges ){
    print( TokenArray , sizeOfTokenArray );
    reversePrint( TokenArray , 0 );
}
```