# Add to end of a doubly linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, doubly-linked-list

I am really struggling in adding a node at the end of a double linked list, adding to the head was easy, now I really can't find a way to add to the end. It seems stupid but I'm losing a lot of time, so if anyone can help that would be appreciated. Here's my partial implementation in Java.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList implements Iterable<Node>, Iterator<Node> {

private Node head = new Node();
private Node tail = head;
private Node current;
private Node previous;

@Override
public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
    current = head;
    previous = null;
    return this;
}

public void addToHead(Node node) {
    Node next = head.getNext(null);
    Node previous = head.getNext(next);
    head.setNext(previous, node);
    node.setNext(null, head);
    head = node;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return current != tail;
}

@Override
public Node next() {
    Node tmp = previous;
    previous = current;
    current = current.getNext(tmp);
    return previous;
}
```

And here's Node Class

```
public class Node {
Node next = null;
Node previous = null;


Node getNext(Node node){
    if(node == next){
        return previous;
    }

    if(node == previous){
        return next;
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("something went wrong");
}

void setNext(Node node, Node next){
    if(node == previous){
        previous = next;
    }
    else if(node == this.next){
        this.next = next;
    }
    else{
        throw new IllegalStateException("something went wrong");
    }
}


}
```

I hope you will understand the code above, basically I will need the following :

```
public void addToEnd(Node node) {
    // implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What interface are you aiming to implement on this double-linked list?  The way you've implemented `getNext` and `setNext` is not a clear way of doing it.  If you only have one node, and you attempt to `setNext` with a `null` value for `node`, there is no way of telling unless you look at the code where your new node is going to end up.  Along with that, I'm not sure if there is a nice way for you to set the previous node of a new tail node with the way you've implemented it.  It's very ambiguous.

Can I recommend that you instead implement `getNext()`, `setNext(Node)`, `getPrevious()` and `setPrevious(Node)` methods in your `Node` class?  This would greatly simplify and clear up your code.

You would then be able to implement your `addToEnd(Node)` method very simply.

```
public void addToEnd(Node node) {
    node.setPrevious(tail);
    tail.setNext(node);
    tail = node;
}
```

If you want to be able to iterate through the list in both directions using 'getNext()' and 'hasNext()', you could provide a forward or reverse `Iterator` implementation.  There are examples of how to create `Iterators` floating around.  The first answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098117/can-one-do-a-for-each-loop-in-java-in-reverse-order/1098137) has an example of a reverse iterator.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is just the same as adding at the beginning of the list.

We can split it up into two parts:

1. adding the item to the list
2. updating the head/tail-node of the list

In pseudocode:

```
node to_insert

//step 1
tail.setNext(to_insert)
to_insert.setPrevious(tail)

//step 2
tail = to_insert
```