# Using a "for each" loop to reverse an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, reverse

I'm having trouble with creating a method for a homework problem to reverse an `ArrayList`in place so that 1 2 3 4 5 for example would become 5 4 3 2 1. I know about `Collections.reverse`, but I can't use it and I can't use a regular for loop, it has to be a "for each" loop so "`for (String book: books) { ... }`". I know that using a regular for loop I would be able to use two iterating variables `i` and `j` so that I could swap values of the first and last index to reverse it, but in a for each loop you can't do that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Given the restrictions you stated I have to ask, Is this homework? If it is, you ought to mention that. Homework is _not_ automatically disqualified from SO, and if you say it is, people tend to give more helpful hints to teach you rather than drop a solution with no explanation.

Comment: Post your code (even psoudo code) for what you did so far. recommendation #1: try solving it with a regular for loop and then try to see how to convert it to for-each (not the same, I know). Recommendation #2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098117/can-one-do-a-for-each-loop-in-java-in-reverse-order

Comment: Hint: you can still declare `int` counters outside the loop and increment them as part of the loop body.

Comment: Hint: ArrayList.size() gives you number of objects inside arraylist

Comment: I am guessing if this is a homework, it would be meant to teach you about Iterable. So read through the Iterable interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and learn how you can implement it.

Comment: If you don't want to any indices at any cost, you could create a new linked list, and use "addLast"  and return new ArrayList<>( linkedlist ). Having said that, the efficient way to do it is using swap as you said, but you need indices.

Comment: A couple of answers since I posted my first comment bring up this question: do you have to reverse the list _in-place?_ That is, given `ArrayList al` are you required to reverse the order of `al` itself, or are you allowed to create & return a _new_ array that is in the reverse order of `al`? _**Or**_ do you merely have to _print_ the reverse of the original array (as bakero98 does)? A clear statement of the problem and goal is _essential_ to Coding the Right Thing.

Comment: I have to reverse the list in place, I'll add that to the op

Comment: @JohnKerry I updated my answer so you should give it a look

Answer (score 1):

This is example using `for each` you create variable containing number of strings inside arrayList and then use regular `for each` loop to go through whole `arrayList` but you print on position `i` and decrement i every time

```
int i = books.size() - 1;
for(String b: books){
 newList.add(books[i]);
 System.out.println(books[i]);
i--;
}
```

This is example for switching inside one arrayList.

```
int i = books.size() - 1;
String helpString;
for(int n = 0; n <= books/2 ; n++){
helpString = books[n];
books[n] = books[i];
books[i] = helpString;

i--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using forEach syntax.

```
List<Integer> intValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intValues.add(1);
intValues.add(2);
intValues.add(3);
intValues.add(4);
intValues.add(5);


 IntStream.range(0, intValues.size()).forEach(v -> System.out.print(intValues.get((intValues.size()-1)-v)));
```