# Iterable Reverse For Each Loop Java

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if there was a way to reverse traverse a Iterable in Java.

```
Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapShotIterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

for (DataSnapshot doc : snapShotIterator) {
    BlogPost blogPost = doc.getValue(BlogPost.class);
    blog_list.add(blogPost);
}
```

Above is my code that I am trying to get to traverse in a reverse order, is there a reverse function for Iterables like there is for Collections?

Thanks in advance!

Hyungjun

Comment: you may check accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098117/can-one-do-a-for-each-loop-in-java-in-reverse-order

Answer (score 2):

You can use Android Studio replace with "For Loop" and then "Reverse it"

```
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("World");

        // Iterate forwards
        for (String string : list) {
            //
        }
```

this is a normal iteration.

Now if you position yourself on top of the `for` statement and do alt-enter (on Linux/Windows, can't remember the macOS shortcut)... you get:

[image: for]

And then, if you do it *again* (alt-enter), you now get the option to reverse the loop:

[image: reversed]

Which looks like this:

```
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            String string = list.get(i);
        }
```

Obviously, this doesn't consider you having an "Iterator" but you get the idea in case you want to iterate over collections directly, without resorting to the Iterator interface.

Comment: You should accomodate the answer to the question use case, can you add a line using iterator get at index?

Answer (score 1):

basically you can reverse the iterable by traversing it and storing it's value in a reverse list, then traverse that list,

you'll have to traverse the iterable at first to be able to do iterate in reverse order

you can use `org.apache.commons.collections.iterators` to do it without implementing yourself

`ReverseListIterator reverseListIterator = new ReverseListIterator(list);`

of course there are a lot of other libs you can use

more can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-iterate-backwards)